# What is the energy at different points of standing wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, waves

I know that the equation of a standing wave in a string is $y=2A\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)$. I also know that the displacement of a node is zero, hence it has zero kinetic energy. How do I find the total energy per unit length at $t=0$ and $x=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conclusion first. The kinetic energy and potential energy of a small string segment of length $\Delta x$ are defined as
$$
E_{kin}=\frac12 \rho \Delta x y_t^2 \\
E_{pot}= \frac12 T_0 \Delta x y_x^2
$$
Where $\rho$ is the linear density of the string (mass/length), $T_0$ is the tension on the string at rest. We have assumed small displacements. $y_t$ and $y_x$ are partial derivatives of $y(x,t)$ with respect to $x$ and $t$.

We can also divide both energy by the segment length $\Delta x$ and get **kinetic energy density** and **potential energy density**.
$$
K.E(x,t) = \frac12 \rho y_t^2 \\
P.E(x,t) = \frac12 T_0  y_x^2
$$
Add them together, we have the **energy density** of the string:
$$
E(x,t)=K.E(x,t)+P.E(x,t)= \frac12 \rho y_t^2 + \frac12 T_0  y_x^2
$$
We can integrate over length L and obtain the total energy of the string:
$$
E_{string} = \int_0^L E(x,t) dx
$$

Now to explain how to get kinetic energy and potential energy of a string. Each small $\Delta x$ segment is associated with two activities, **oscillating vertically** and **stretching its length**. The oscillation contains kinetic energy $1/2 m v_y^2$, where $m = \rho \Delta x$ and $v_y=y_t$. The stretching contains potential energy, which is of the form $F\cdot \Delta L$. Here $F=T_0$ is a constant force along the string, $\Delta L$ is:
$$
\Delta L = \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2} - \Delta x = \Delta x (\sqrt{1+y_x^2} - 1) \approx \frac12 y_x^2 \Delta x
$$

Comment: At any point on a string, is the sum of kinetic and potential energy constant?

Comment: Not necessarily. To check that, calculate $\partial E(x,t) / \partial t$ and see if it's zero. There's also a simplified expression $\partial E(x,t) / \partial t = T_0 \partial / \partial_x (y_x y_t)$

Comment: I calculated $\partial E/\partial t$ for your standing wave, and my result shows that only when $cos(2kx)=0$ do we have a point whose energy density is conserved.

Comment: @Liuke LYU  the enrgy time variation  is equal to the -div of the Poynting vector. For a standing wave I would assume the Poynting vector is 0. Your result is rather surprising.

Comment: So if at some instant a particle on string has some energy and at another instant it has some different magnitude of energy..where is the differmece of energy going?...is it being passed onto the neighboring particles?

Comment: I was taught that each particle of string will perform simple harmonic motion..so its energy must remain constant

Comment: Take the antinode for example, where the small segment is flat and is never stretched, so it only has kinetic energy. We know it oscillates and changes speed, so its total energy must also change, transferred to and from neighbouring segments. Now you could also try to isolate your antinode segment and define a potential energy $1/2kx^2$ so that the energy is conserved. But then you have to justify this choice by some physical argument.